# Eclipse doesn't recognise @Inject?

Tags: spring, pom.xml, inject, autowired

Eclipse is not recognising @Inject in my JSF-Apache Myfaces/Spring/Hibernate project.

I am trying to use it on a setter method to inject a reference to a Class I've registered with the Spring container as a @Component, @SessionScoped.

What gives? I appear to have the latest version of Spring defined in my POM.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`@Inject` is not a Spring annotation, but an annotation brought about by [JSR-330](http://www.jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=330).  It is an annotation that Spring supports and it is synonymous with the `@Autowired` annotation.

You have to make sure that you have the jar that contains `@Inject`, because it is not a part of the standard JDK.  You can download the jar from [here](http://grepcode.com/snapshot/repo1.maven.org/maven2/javax.inject/javax.inject/1), or you can use this maven dependency:

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>javax.inject</groupId>
  <artifactId>javax.inject</artifactId>
  <version>1</version>
</dependency>
```